# Most basic Pod definition for testing purpose of API service

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop

I have an API Service running as a Docker Image and now I want to test it on Kubernetes with Docker Desktop,  but I can't get it running.
The docker image's name is `api_service`

this is the yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-api-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-api-service
  replicas: 1 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-api-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api_service
        image: api_service
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5001
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-api-service
spec:
  selector:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5001
      targetPort: 5001
```

By checking with `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`,
The status is `ImagePullBackOff`.
What am I doing wrong?

update:

calling kubectl describe:

```
Name:         my-api-service-7ffdb9d6b7-x5zs8
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         docker-desktop/192.168.65.4
Start Time:   Mon, 15 Aug 2022 13:55:47 +0200
Labels:       app=my-api-service
              pod-template-hash=7ffdb9d6b7
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Pending
IP:           10.1.0.15
IPs:
  IP:           10.1.0.15
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/my-api-service-7ffdb9d6b7
Containers:
  my-api-service:
    Container ID:   
    Image:          api_service
    Image ID:       
    Port:           5001/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-hgghw (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-hgghw:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason   Age                    From     Message
  ----    ------   ----                   ----     -------
  Normal  BackOff  4m37s (x413 over 99m)  kubelet  Back-off pulling image "api_service"
```

Comment: Not knowing how you deployed kubernetes, we can't tell much. Although it would be normal for kubernetes not to know where to pull that image from, if you did not publish it to a registry. Running kubernetes as a container in your desktop doesn't mean kubernetes has access to your container runtime. While docker itself is now deprecated as a runtime (https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/02/dont-panic-kubernetes-and-docker/). Depending on your k8s version, might have been removed already..

Comment: I simply enabled Kubernetes in the Docker Desktop preferences, as described in the documentation. What information about the deployment would you need?

Comment: Change  `mage: api_service` to `mage: nginx` and it should work

Comment: @Adiii still not working

Comment: then check why its fialing `kubectl describe pod podname`

Comment: @Adiii I updated the post with the pod description

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a built image in a repository and not use a local docker image. Kubernetes does not share the repository with your local docker/crd image rep. As I see, you built an image with a tag, and then you want to use it in k8s/deployment, which should not be done. You can however, link kubernetes with your local image docker repository and try it that way. But still, k8s is a big whale and doing this in production may cause grave mistakes. Please follow this [link](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-run-locally-built-docker-images-in-kubernetes-b28fbc32cc1d)

Altough anytime you dont know where the problem is, you can check the **kubelet** logs, as **kubelet** pulls the images. Depending on your k8s version, run the command to get logs from the kubelet